# TeamCity file storage for config files

Tags: teamcity

is there a way in the TeamCity to have application config files with production passwords stored in the TeamCity?

During build/deployment these files will be used for different environments.
For example in the project repository you have app.config file which is filled with Development env secrets. And you don't want to store production envs secrets in the repository.

Need exact file because it's not only a single values which could be covered with Configuration Parameters, it could be big XML pieces. So better to have a whole app.config file somewhere in the TeamCity configured which I can use to publish to production env.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I know in Team city administration you can configure each build configuration as administrator. And for build configuration, you can find the parameters section where you can add parameters as secret values. These values would be available during the build process but they would not be logged. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Let's imaging that production config file is 50% differ from development config file. And it's not only a simple key-value settings, it's complex XML sections.